# Spring Reactive WebSockets and Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, spring-websocket

I've seen examples how to use WebSockets with Spring Webflux.  These are fine, but I'd like WebSockets to work together with coroutines.  Specifically, I want data sent to a `Channel` from a coroutine to be sent over the WebSocket, and send data received through the WebSocket into another `Channel`.

What would be a convenient way to do this?  Preferably closing of the `Channel` would lead to closing of the WebSocket connection and vice versa.